# phalcon MVC Model

Tags: model-view-controller, phalcon

I had a problem with the mvc model updating a row.
The task was:
**in table `table_name` set `column_name` = `column_name` + 1**

If i would use the model like

```
model->find(...)    
model->column_name = model->column_name + 1
model->save
```

then another script could have updated the column in the mean time:

```
model->find(...)    
model->column_name = model->column_name + 1 // lets say loaded 9 and set to 10
// at this point another script may just loaded the old value 9
// and saved it to n.
// my current model would save to to 10 which would be wrong
model->save
```

To prevent that Im using the server:

```
$result = $this->getWriteConnection()->query(
    "UPDATE `table_name` SET 
                  `column_name` = @new_value := `column_name` + 1 
                  WHERE ...;"
);
```

I then select the @new_value session var on another call.

---

What Im searching now is a way to do that with the mvc model.
Any way to do that?

Comment: If it will be incremented by one on each update or something like this then use mysql trigger.

Comment: But then i would have to set this up for every adapter -- if even possible (f.e. switching over to mongo)